# Empty a data.frame (keep colnames/headers only)

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know what is the proper way to empty a data frame in R.

I need to keep colnames only.

---

Example:

```
id | fruit
---+------------
1  | strawberry
2  | blackberry
3  | apple
4  | peer
```

would, after the operation, be:

```
id | fruit
---+------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
df <- df[FALSE, ]

#[1] id    fruit
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DF <- iris
str(DF[NULL,])
#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num 
#$ Sepal.Width : num 
#$ Petal.Length: num 
#$ Petal.Width : num 
#$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..:
```